# Accidentally deleted /etc/apt/apt.conf.d

Tags: apt, etc

I accidentally deleted the apt.conf.d folder and can’t install (use the apt-get) anything.

When I try to locate the `apt.conf.d` in the apt folder, it’s no longer there, only `sources.list` can be found.
So that means that the `apt.conf.d` is not the only thing missing in the folder.

The main question is:
**How can I recreate/restore/retrieve the whole apt folder?**

Additional:

While using apt-get in the terminal, I always get the error:

```
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/preferences.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

It’s not in the trash because I used root access via terminal (so it’s deleted permanently, unfortunately).

**EDIT:**
The `apt.conf.d` folder has been recreated but how about the `preferences.d`? What type of file should I recreate? (What is the default content of the `preferences.d` and `apt.conf.d`?)

Comment: Is that still exists in trash folder? or deleted permanently?

Comment: can't you just create the folder using `sudo mkdir /etc/apt/apt.conf.d` ?

Comment: @nanne probably correct. Found a source stating the same ;)

Answer (score 6):

According to [bug 578446](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=578446) on debian this also happens when you change distribution from command line using `chdist`. And it also states that recreating the directory should be enough.

Comment: @Noob no problem. Don't forget to accept and upvote if no other person has a better answer (and if you feel like it ;) )

Comment: @Noob btw I have no preferences.d here on my server...

Answer (score -1):

```
touch apt.conf
```

and then

```
sudo vi apt.conf
```

Next add the proxy,

edit the file and make sure in the below format:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "proxy:port-number/";
```